# Vectorization of values based upon values of contiguous rows

Tags: r, vectorization, xts, zoo, moving-average

Consider the following (example) `zoo` object:

[image: example zoo object]

The data frame is sorted in ascending order on the **date** index. The **ma3** field provides the 3-day moving average value of the **duration** field. The **comparison** field compares the value of the **duration** value to the corresponding **ma3** value; (1) IF **duration** > **ma3** THEN 'ABOVE', (2) IF **duration** < **ma3** THEN 'BELOW', (3) ELSE 'EQUAL'.

The values for the **consec_day** field are calculated as follows: Starting from the earliest date *with a ma3 value* if the **comparison** value equals 'ABOVE' then the sign of the **consec_day** value is positive, if the **comparison** value equals 'BELOW' then the sign of the **consec_day** value is negative, and if the **comparison** value equals 'EQUAL' then the **consec_day** *value* is zero. To determine the magnitude of the **consec_day** value, count the number of consecutive (from oldest to most recent), identical **comparison** values.

Questions:

1. Can the computation of the **consec_day** field be vectorized?
2. If so, how?

My current solution uses loops as follows:

```
    z0 <- zoo(matrix(c(c(345, 432, 112, 332, 496, 414, 211), c(NA, NA, 296.33, 292, 313.33, 414, 373.67), c(NA, NA, 'BELOW', 'ABOVE', 'ABOVE', 'EQUAL', 'BELOW'), c(NA, NA, -1, 1, 2, 0, -1)), nrow = 7, ncol = 4), seq(as.Date('2013-07-31'), as.Date('2013-08-06'), by = "day"))
    colnames(z0) <- c("duration", "ma3", "comparison", "consec_day")
    require(xts)
    for (r in 1:nrow(z0)) {
      if (is.na(z0$comparison[r])) {next}
      if (z0$comparison[r] == 'EQUAL') {z0$consec_day[r] <- 0; next}
      if (is.na(z0$comparison[r - 1])) {z0$consec_day[r] <- ifelse(z0$comparison[r] == 'ABOVE', 1, ifelse(z0$comparison[r] == 'BELOW', -1, 0)); next}
      if ( (xts::coredata(df0)[r, 3] != xts::coredata(df0)[r - 1, 3]) & xts::coredata(df0)[r, 3] == 'ABOVE') {
        df0$consec_day[r] <- 1 
      } else {
      if ( (xts::coredata(df0)[r, 3] != xts::coredata(df0)[r - 1, 3]) & xts::coredata(df0)[r, 3] == 'BELOW') {
        df0$consec_day[r] <- -1 
      } else {ifelse((xts::coredata(df0)[r, 3] != xts::coredata(df0)[r - 1, 3]) & xts::coredata(df0)[r, 3] == 'ABOVE')), df0$consec_day[r] <- df0$consec_day[r - 1] + 1, df0$consec_day[r] <- df0$consec_day[r - 1] - 1}
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (a screenshot of your data makes it hard work to reproduce)

Comment: Also, `consec_day` appears to be based on `comparison` of the row below - is that correct?

Comment: I originally loaded a bad (= inconsistent) image. The updated image should be correct. Apologies.

Comment: @Jubbles - the content of the image isn't a problem. That you posted an image is - do you expect those answering to manually type in your data to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I just added code for the example `zoo` object. Again apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `run length encoding` (`rle`)

You will need to pass an atomic vector (and replace the leading `NA` values with `'.NA'` as `rle` doesn't really deal well with them)

```
comparison <- z0[,3]
compAtomic <- as.character(comparison)
compAtomic[is.na(compAtomic)] <- '.NA'

# define your changes
changes <- c('BELOW' =-1, 'EQUAL' = 0, 'ABOVE' = 1, '.NA' = NA )
# perform rle (and unclass the results)
rrl <- unclass(rle(compAtomic))
# a bit of `rep` and `sequence`
with(rrl, sequence(lengths) * rep(changes[values],lengths))
#  .NA   .NA BELOW ABOVE ABOVE EQUAL BELOW 
#   NA    NA    -1     1     2     0    -1
```